# How can I get the previous Location, once I visited a location in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, url, path, location

The following snippet only works once I leave the current Location. I need the previousLocation right at the beginning. How can I achieve this?

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(e, currentLocation, previousLocation){
      console.log('locationChange');
      //alert(previousLocation);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "right at the beginning"? When the page loads?

Comment: Yes. Once my Page loaded, I want to save the previous location in my database.

Comment: So this location isn't necessarily one of your app, right? I could come to your app from an external site.

Comment: If it is one of my app, I will use it. Otherwise I would ignore it. Seems like there is no easy way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `document.referrer` and check if the URL matches your app using something like this:

```
document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) > -1
```